# How to combine/merge pages in pdf file (GUI)?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I want to combine two pages in pdf file into single page.

Consider I have a pdf file in which there are **two pages**, now I want to **combine two pages into (single) one**, No-matter for (how-long) page-size!

How to do that?

**Note:** *This question is not about combine two pdf files or merging pdf files or adding pages in pdf files.*

Also visit [Question about scaling page in pdf](https://askubuntu.com/q/492733/256099).

Answer (score 4):

**PDFJam** (Not a GUI app)

Multiple pages can be combined with it.

```
sudo apt-get install pdfjam
```

Then you need to use the `pdfnup` command to combine pages:

```
pdfnup -2 [INPUT].pdf [OUTPUT].pdf
```

This will combine two input pages per one output page.

Refer to [`man pdfnup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pdfnup.1) for more details.

Also refer this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535794/how-can-i-combine-two-pdf-pages-show-up-on-the-same-page) question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an *OpenSource* solution I highly recommend to look at [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/), which comes with a huge pack of useful features to merge, split and "alternate mix" PDF files.

[image]

[Here's a brief guide](http://www.ryadel.com/en/scan-both-sides-of-a-front-back-document-in-a-single-pdf-with-pdfsam) explaining what it can do, with a strong focus on the *Alternate Mix* feature which is one of its major strenghts.

Answer (score 1):

Sejda is an online service based on an open source PDF engine and the [N-Up feature](https://www.sejda.com/n-up-pdf) should do what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 18.04 i installed texlive-extra-utils (which contains pdfjam)

```
sudo apt install texlive-extra-utils
```

and then for 2 pages:

```
pdfnup --batch --suffix 2up my_pdf_file.pdf
```

or for 4pages in table 2x2 format:

```
pdfjam my_pdf_file.pdf --no-landscape --frame true --nup 2x2 --suffix 4up  --outfile ~/Desktop/
```

Comment: pdfjam still works on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**PDF-Shuffler** is a GUI PDF app that allows you to merge, shuffle and delete PDF pages.

Install with;

```
Sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately this is only good for simple reordering of pages and merging *documents*. The question appears to be about merging *pages* within a single document.

Comment: Now it is `apt install pdfarranger`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install additional software.

Use the **Print to PDF** feature of your favourite pdf viewer.

For example: Open your pdf file *evince* and print with two pages to one side, select *Print to PDF* or a pdf printer that is installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pdftools](https://github.com/raffaem/pdftools) with the `--nup` option:

```
pdftools.py  --input-file input.pdf --output output.pdf --nup 2 1
```

This will generate an output pdf file where a page of the output file is the combination of two pages of the input file, up and down.

If you want to combine them left and right, just switch the parameters of the `--nup` option:

```
pdftools.py  --input-file input.pdf --output output.pdf --nup 1 2
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use ghostscript to combine various pdf documents into one, using the following command in terminal:

*assuming we have two pdf documents named `doc1.pdf` and `doc2.pdf` and we want to combine them into a newly document named combined.pdf*

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=combined.pdf -dBATCH doc1.pdf doc2.pdf
```

or for all files in directory

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=combined.pdf -dBATCH *.pdf
```