# How do I scale page in pdf files in Ubuntu? (GUI)

Tags: pdf, master-pdf-editor

I want to scale page in pdf file. In other words I want to change in Height & width of page in pdf file.

How do I do that?

**Note**: *This question is not about scale page during/for printing!*

Also visit [Question about combine two pages in pdf.](https://askubuntu.com/q/492726/256099)

Comment: see [this](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) and use `cpdf -scale-to-fit a4portrait in.pdf -o out.pdf` to solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to have my DIN A4 document upscaled to DIN A3.
On my computer at work, I don't have `pdfpages` installed, but I do have `pdfjam`, so here is an alternative solution for that particular case:

`pdfjam --a3paper input.pdf -o output.pdf`

Answer (score 4):

**PDFPoster** (Not a GUI app)

This will scale a pdf file.

```
sudo apt-get install pdfposter
```

Scaling can be done with following command:

```
pdfposter -s[SCALING RATIO] [INPUT].pdf [OUTPUT].pdf
```

Example: `pdfposter -s4 input.pdf out.pdf`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package pdfposter