# Question on pdf

Tags: pdf

Is there any way in a pdf to have 2 sheets in one page?

I mean a pdf file of 500 pages, to be modified in a pdf with 250 pages(2 sheets on every page).

Is there any software /program online like ''small pdf''?

Comment: Open in evince, print with two pages to a side.

Comment: @muru is there any other way so it can be a new pdf file?

Comment: Select Print to PDF when printing, then it will create a new PDF.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/492726/37165) asked on "How to combine/merge pages in pdf file (GUI)?" has answers for GUI and command line methods, including `pdfnup`.

Comment: People have directed me at pdfposter for similar issues - I believe that it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the command line using `pdfnup` (part of the "PDFjam" package of tools)

```
NAME

   pdfnup - n-up the pages of pdf files

SYNOPSIS
       pdfnup [OPTION [OPTION] ...] [SRC [PAGESPEC] [SRC [PAGESPEC]] ...]

DESCRIPTION
       pdfnup  converts  files  in the Adobe Portable Document Format (PDF) to
       "n-up" PDF files, that is, with multiple input pages per  output  page,
       for  more  economical  printing etc.  The default processing is to 2-up
       landscape output with no frame around pages, equivalent  to  using  the
       options '--nup 2x1 --landscape true --frame false'.
```